# How to open own context menu at cursor coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have own my contextmenu which I want to call and set its coordinates to X and Y coordinates. How can I do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/coolerprinter/xg10vzeL/

This code isn't valid and does not work:

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", function(e){
    var x = function(e) { 
        return e.pageX 
    };
    var y = function(e) { 
        return e.pageY 
    };

    $(".contextmenu").css({
        "display": "block",
        "left": x,
        "top": y
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You've to call the functions with an argument instead of setting references to style values. Or just use `e.pageX/Y` instead of `x` and `y`. Notice also, that the height of the empty body is `0`, you can't click on that.

Comment: Please tell us why you are depending the contextmenu on mous cursor coordinates instead on HTML/DOM elements?

Comment: Sorry, I forget. But  function also didn't work!

Comment: Teemu, BODY isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to hook the event to the `document`, not the `body`. Secondly you need to provide the actual values of `pageX` and `pageY` to the `left` and `top` CSS properties, not functions. Try this:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".contextmenu").css({
        "display": "block",
        "left": e.pageX,
        "top": e.pageY
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xg10vzeL/3/)

To expand this to behave like a normal context menu, where it disappears when a click occurs outside it, then you need an additional `click` handler on the document:

```
$(document).on({
    contextmenu: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".contextmenu").css({
            "display": "block",
            "left": e.pageX,
            "top": e.pageY
        });
    },
    click: function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is('.contextmenu') || $target.closest('.contextmenu').length) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $(".contextmenu").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xg10vzeL/4/)